# $(\mathbb Z_p-\{0\},\times_p)$ is a group for prime $p?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to show that $(\mathbb Z_p-\{0\},\times_p)$ is a group for prime $p?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** A finite set that's closed under an associative product in which both the cancellation laws hold form a group. (A suggestion directly from Prof. Herstein)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to show that closure, associativity and identity hold. To show that every element has an inverse, use [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

**Hint:** Any nonzero $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p - \{ 0 \}$ is coprime to $p$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to show that the product is associative, has an identity and that the product of two non-zero in $\mathbb{Z/pZ}$ is non-zero.

To see there is an inverse see that for a fixed $a$ the function $x\mapsto a\times_p x$ is injective, and therefore is surjective, and so there is some $b$ such that $a\times_p b=1$.

To see that this map is injective assume $ax=ay$ and therefore $p|ax-ay=a(x-y)$ but $p\nmid a$ and is prime, so $p|(x-y)$ and so it has to be that $x\equiv_p y$ as wanted.